# Zooming in dope sheet. Change to zoom at current mouse-position?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

In 2.79 in the Dope Sheet editor.

Is there a way to change the mousewheel-zoom style from: "Zoom to the middle of the track."

to

"Zoom wherever the mouse currently is ?"

Coming from video editing, this seems much more intuitive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function was added in 2.8

[image]